# Java Mail API: send emails via corporate outlook acount

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want my program to be able to send emails from my corporate outlook account. I looked at many JMA examples the do not seem to be what I want.

1. Where can I find simple examples of sending mails via outlook?
2. Should I move mailing system to separate service-application? and if so, why?

Comment: Did you try any command-lines to try sending commands to the Outlook application via Java?

Comment: Have a look at a related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4681703/how-to-send-an-email-using-ms-exchange-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is your SMTP settings for your corporate account. Set these in your program using Java mail API and thats it. e.g.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "your server here");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
```

example: [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) and [here](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075785/java-se/javamail-quick-start.html)

Comment: what should be the server for outlook? Provide me example, please

Comment: Check your outlook configuration, or ask the admin\network team. Or if you are using Outlook web access, check outlook about page e.g. https://server_name_here/owa/?ae=Options&opturl=Messaging

Comment: thanks it works. But I need to send emails on behalf of special user/acount. How should I set username/password?

Comment: please see the examples posted. You can use e.g. msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("admin@example.com", "Example.com Admin"));

Comment: I just can't grasp what is the second argument in InternetAddress constructor. As I understand without providing username/password I will send email on behalf of already logined user. Am I right? But I need to send emails on behalf of testUser/12345. Can you provide me a litle example?

Comment: Hello. What if I don't want to include the username/password of the sender on the code? Can I do that?

Answer (score 11):

You need to download `javax.mail` JAR first. Then try the following code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMail {

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {

        final String username = "enter your username";
        final String password = "enter your password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "outlook.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("enter your outlook mail address"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("Enter the recipient mail address"));
            message.setSubject("Test");
            message.setText("HI");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for me.  I keep getting an error saying "550 5.2.1 Mailbox cannot be accessed".   A colleague of mine is using the same credentials, although in C#, and calling an exchange web service, and it's working for him.

Comment: Thank you for the code, But getting hunged in Transport.send(message); line.

Comment: It could be because of proxy. Could you please check the same?

Answer (score 2):

I tried with `outlook.office365.com` as a host name and got `authentication unaccepted exception`. When trying with `smtp-mail.outlook.com`
I'm able to send mails through outlook with `Javamail API`.

For further detail [Check out the settings of Outlook](https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-com-pop-settings/) on outlook official site.

For complete working demo code [Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218352/how-to-send-an-email-from-outlook-via-java/41347253#41347253).

Answer (score -2):

From what I can see, you are missing the following import:

```
import java.io.IOException;
```

Just include it in the class imports at the peginning of this class and your issue should be solved.

Comment: Can you expand on this answer? Moderators generally look for answers with more substance that give a more complete example of the necessary solution.