# How to send an email from Outlook via Java?

Tags: java, apache, email, outlook, jakarta-mail

I am stuck behind a corporate firewall that won't let me send email via conventional means such as Java Mail API or Apache Commons Email, even to other people inside the organization(which is all I want anyways). But my Outlook 2010 obviously can send these emails. I was wondering if there is a way to automate Outlook 2010 via Java code so that Outlook can send the emails ? I know stuff like "mailto" can be used pop-up the default Outlook send dialog with pre-populated info, but I am looking for a way to have the send operation happen behind the scenes. Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 8):

You can send emails through outlook with `javamail` use the configurations described on [Outlook's official site.](https://www.outlook-apps.com/outlook-com-pop-settings/)

Here is small demo code

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String username = "your email";  // like yourname@outlook.com
    final String password = "*********";   // password here

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp-mail.outlook.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
      new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
      });
    session.setDebug(true);

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("receiver mail"));   // like inzi769@gmail.com
        message.setSubject("Test");
        message.setText("HI you have done sending mail with outlook");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

.
**Note:** I tested this with `Javamail API 1.5.6`

Comment: I think the OP did not mean to use Microsoft's email server, but Microsoft's email client program. Confusingly both are named 'outlook'.

Comment: import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do what you want using Outlook.

Presumably your mail server is also behind the corporate firewall.  If you're using Outlook for your client, you're probably using Exchange for your server.  Exchange can be configured to support the standard SMTP protocol for sending mail, which would allow use of JavaMail.  If you can't configure your Exchange server to support SMTP, you still might be able to use [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx).  If that doesn't work, you might need to use one of the [JavaMail Third Party Products](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/third-party-136965.html) that supports the Microsoft proprietary mail protocol.

Answer (score -1):

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C start outlook ");
```

Comment: Wouldn't this start the Outlook GUI? That seems to be the opposite of what OP is looking for. Sorry I couldn't contribute more however.