# Sending HTML through Java to any email address

Tags: java, email, outlook, send

I want to send a simple HTML table which is saved in a java variable:

```
String table = "<table border=1> <tr><td>blabla</td></tr> </table>";
```

in outlook to any email address. The HTML should be formatted and not in plain text.

How do I do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this post :

[Java Mail API: send emails via corporate outlook acount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20613569/java-mail-api-send-emails-via-corporate-outlook-acount)

It might be useful to you.